# Curl command failing with uploading particular Avro Schema that uploads fine in Postman

Tags: curl, postman, schema, apache-pulsar

In pulsar, I've been writing some simple BASH scripts to create and upload topics to my namespace using curl commands:

```bash
function create_partioned_topic {
    echo -e "\n+++ Creating partioned topic: $TOPIC +++"
    curl --location --request PUT "https://$PULSAR_HOST:$HOST_PULSAR_PORT/admin/v2/persistent/$TENANT/$NAMESPACE/$TOPIC/partitions" \
        --verbose \
        --header "Authorization: Bearer $AUTHORIZATION"  \
        --insecure \
        --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        --data-raw '3' 2>&1 | cat | grep "HTTP" # grep -v "Authorization"
}

function uploading_topic {
    echo -e "\n\n+++ Uploading $TOPIC +++"
    curl --location --request POST "https://$PULSAR_HOST:$HOST_PULSAR_PORT/admin/v2/schemas/$TENANT/$NAMESPACE/$TOPIC/schema" \
        --verbose \
        --header "Authorization: Bearer $AUTHORIZATION"  \
        --insecure \
        --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        --data-raw $SCHEMA 2>&1 | cat | grep "HTTP" # grep -v "Authorization"
}
```

These commands work fine except for the following I'm trying to upload:

```bash
TOPIC=nested_schema
NESTED_SCHEMA='{"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"DatasetEventSchema\",\"namespace\":\"channels.$TENANT.$NAMESPACE.$TOPIC.generated\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"DataRecord\",\"type\":{\"name\":\"DataRecordSchema\",\"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"description\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"created_by\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"updated_by\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"created_at\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"updated_at\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"data_legitimacy\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"item_status\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"tenant_id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"tags\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"dataset_series_id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"location_id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"provided_by\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"metadata\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}},{\"name\":\"MetadataRecord\",\"type\":{\"name\":\"MetadataRecordSchema\",\"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"timestamp\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"record_type\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"operation\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"partition_key_type\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"schema_name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"table_name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"transaction_id\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}}]}","type":"AVRO","properties":{}}'
```

When I'm uploading this Schema via a curl command, it seems to never complete. I get the notification that it's beginning to post, but it never finishes.

Other schemas I upload work just fine. Two examples are:

```bash
TOPIC=double_nested_schema
DOUBLE_NESTED_SCHEMA='{"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"DoubleNestedSchema\",\"namespace\":\"channels.$TENANT.$NAMESPACE.$TOPIC.generated\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"DataRecord\",\"type\":{\"name\":\"DataRecordSchema\",\"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"IdRecord\",\"type\":{\"name\":\"IdRecordSchema\",\"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}}]}},{\"name\":\"MetadataRecord\",\"type\":{\"name\":\"MetadataRecordSchema\",\"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"timestamp\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}}]}","type":"AVRO","properties":{}}'

TOPIC=simplest_schema
SIMPLEST_SCHEMA='{"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"SimplestExample\",\"namespace\":\"channels.$TENANT.$NAMESPACE.$TOPIC.generated\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}","type":"AVRO","properties":{}}'
```

#### Things I've tried

- As I mentioned above, I've tried the two different schemas `SIMPLEST_SCHEMA` and `DOUBLE_NESTED_SCHEMA` and they work fine
- I've also tested running the equivalent of uploading my `NESTED_SCHEMA` in Postman and it works fine. Does this indicate there's something about curl that doesn't like my formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a number of solutions, but I kept finding that this worked fine in Postman but not as curl command.

When I turned on the `--verbose` header I saw that I was getting hung up at about this point:

```bash
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
* Done waiting for 100-continue
```

Evidently this behavior is done when:

- the request is a PUT or
- the request is a POST and the data size is larger than 1024 bytes

You can turn off this behavior by setting the `Except` header to an empty string.

like so:

curl -H 'Expect:'

This version of the curl command ended up working for me:

```bash
    curl --location --request POST "https://$PULSAR_HOST:$HOST_PULSAR_PORT/admin/v2/schemas/$TENANT/$NAMESPACE/$TOPIC/schema" \
        --verbose \
        --header 'Expect:' \
        --header "Authorization: Bearer $AUTHORIZATION"  \
        --insecure \
        --header "Content-Type: $content_type" \
        --data-raw $SCHEMA 2>&1 | grep "HTTP" # grep -v "Authorization"
```

See references:

- https://gms.tf/when-curl-sends-100-continue.html
- https://curl.se/mail/lib-2017-07/0013.html

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, After fixing the single quotes, I tried sending that problematic schema via curl on this [site](https://reqbin.com/req/c-dwjszac0/curl-post-json-example) and specifying the content type as `application/json`. When I did, I received the error: `You selected 'application/json' content type, but the provided string is not a valid JSON string.`

Based on this, it appears that your JSON is malformed.

Comment: Thanks for that, I did have the correct '' characters on my personal script. I've also updated the incorrectly formatted example above in my  original question.

I tried using the site you recommended and see if I could also get it work but when I click the run key I'm getting the error: `You selected 'application/json' content type, but the provided string is not a valid JSON string.`

But you weren't getting that error?

Comment: Good catch. I hadn't specified application/json.  when I do that I get the same error that you mention. Based on that, one has to assume that your JSON is malformed and that is causing the issue

Comment: Thank you for your help David. If you want to update your solution regarding the `application/json` problem I'll mark it as correct.